# Match only if conditions are true

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'd like to get help with making a Regex match in JavaScript

---

**Match the number only:**

- If the **row** (Odd) has a **number larger than 25**  AND the **row
  after** (Even) has the word "**Apples**" in it.

  - **Explanation**:

    - The **first row's** value (29) belongs to the **second row** ("First | Cocoa Apples are")
    - The **third row's** value (23) to the **fourth row** ("Second | Test Text") *... and so on...*

---

**The TEXT I will be using it with:**

```
29% OK
First | Cocoa Apples are
23% NOT
Second | Test Text
18% NOT
Third | Mango Alpa Tango
16% NOT
Fourth | Apples are
33% OK
Fifth | Text Testing App
10% NOT
Sixth | Apples are Gold Duck
28% OK
Seventh | Alpa Apples are Tango
66% OK
Eighth | Oh My Apples are Avocado
20% NOT
Ninth | This Is My Text
25% NOT
Tenth | This Is Hard
```

Comment: I doubt that any Regex flavour can compare numbers like that..

Comment: And what would you like to get as a match? Only the number? First sentence or the second one? Or both?

Comment: @Stefan it is possible

Comment: So, I understood your conditions now but what would you want to match? I mean which part of string?

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Well, you proved me wrong ^^ didn't think of it that way

Comment: @Stefan regex can be really powerful. If it is clearly defined one can match almost anything :)

Comment: I wanted to match the number.(sorry for not stating it).

Comment: @Enryu I already gave you some solutions below please check them. and please edit you question according to "I wanted to match the number".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(2[5-9]|[3-9][0-9])%(?=.*\n.*Apples)/g
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a regex, but I think the following does a pretty good job with finding the numbers and lines:

```js
var str = `29% OK
First | Cocoa Apples are
23% NOT
Second | Test Text
18% NOT
Third | Mango Alpa Tango
16% NOT
Fourth | Apples are
33% OK
Fifth | Text Testing App
10% NOT
Sixth | Apples are Gold Duck
28% OK
Seventh | Alpa Apples are Tango
66% OK
Eighth | Oh My Apples are Avocado
20% NOT
Ninth | This Is My Text
25% NOT
Tenth | This Is Hard`;


var bigger = false;
str.split("\n").forEach(function(row, i) {
  if (i % 2 == 0 && parseInt(row.replace(/\\D/g, ""), 10) >= 25) {
      bigger = true;    
  } else {
    if (bigger) {
      bigger = false;
      if (row.indexOf("Apples") > -1) {
        console.log("match in line " + i );  
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks,but I needed it in Regex.Appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Here, it should work as your request

```
^(?:(?:.*\n){2})*?((?:2[6-9]|[3-9][0-9]|100)).*\n.*Apples
```

**Explanations**

`^(?:(?:.*\n){2})*?` match zero line or even number of lines,

`((?:2[6-9]|[3-9][0-9]|100))` group number of percentage which larger than 25 to variable `\1`,

`.*\n.*Apples` match line that has the word `"Apples"`.

see, [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mT9hN3/4)

Note that because of some limitation of lookbehind in javascript, it's much more convenience to capture number of percentage than just match it.

**Some more straightforward way**

```
(?:2[6-9]|[3-9][0-9]|100)(?=.*\n.*Apples)
```

I think this approach is more easy than the first one because you don't need to deal with such fancy words like "odd" or "even".

see, [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tY3xU0/3)

Comment: This is not "entirely" what I wanted ,since It matches ,if either of my conditions is true(I. 25< number   II. has "Apples" in it.Someone already answered it perfectly at the top,but THANKS for your help!

Comment: It has been answered,but **Thanks !**

Comment: How would you change your code,if it not only has to match a word("Apples"),but the whole line? ("First | Cocoa Apples are") I've tried changing it,but because of the | symbol,I couldn't get it to work..Please use this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tY3xU0/3) .

Comment: I think I made it,but please check it out.[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aM4cT5/1)

Comment: `(?:2[6-9]|[3-9][0-9]|100)(?=.*\n.*Apples)`, `\n` is a newline right? `.*` is any characters till `Apples`. So, you should write this `(?:2[6-9]|[3-9][0-9]|100)(?=.*\nFirst \| Cocoa Apples are)`

Comment: If you use non-capturing group instead of positive lookahead at last group `(?:2[6-9]|[3-9][0-9]|100)(?:.*\nFirst \| Cocoa Apples are)` you will see in regex101 that it will be matched as you wish. But please be careful of `|`. Basically it's an "alteration operator". Please use `\|` for matching character `|`. I might recommend you to download regex cheat sheet from the internet. It's totally useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
(2[5-9]|[3-9][0-9]|100)%.*\n.*Apples.*
```

if you need to capture all text.

Comment: Thanks! Someone was faster(and I only needed the number value(sorry for not stating it)),but I appreciate the help!